# Symbolic Math with n

Tags: symbolic-math

Suppose we want to find summation formula for a sequence. The easiest one would be

x1 = 1; x2 = 2; ... ; xn = n; ...

We all know the sum of the first **n** items is (**n**+1)**n**/2.

My question is how to find the last formula using symbolic calculation with Sympy or matlab or any other software. The difficulty I have is how to deal with **n**. For example, if each entry in a sequence can be written as a function of **n**, such as, an = n^2, where n=1, 2, ... Now how do I use symbolic calculation to get a formula for a1+a2+...+an, please? Note I want a formula in terms of a general **n** without specify a value for **n**. Is this even possible? If so, how? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the syntax of your symbolic math software. For example: here is the solution using Wolfram alpha: [Sum[i, {i, 1, n}]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[i%2C%20%7Bi%2C%201%2C%20n%7D])
- n is just n - that's why it is called symbolic.

Answer (score 0):

As @ChistianFries say, dealing with an arbitrary symbolic variable like your `n` is what symbolic math is all about.

In Matlab, you should start by reading up on the [Symbolic Math toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) and (optionally) [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad-1.html), which is a separate environment a bit like Mathematica. Symbolic summation can be accomplished in Matlab via [`symsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symsum.html):

```
syms x n;
symsum(x,1,n)
```

which returns `(n*(n + 1))/2` as expected. I recommend reading the documentation for `symsum`, and the other symbolic math functions, and trying out the examples provided.